# Apparently I've got a temporary profile which needs fixing, but the fix didn't work

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles

Over last weekend my Windows 10 machine got the May 2019 update (1903). At first it seemed fine, but I began to notice some issues. First in Outlook, as it lost track of where a .pst file was. Also Dropbox couldn't find where I had assigned storage on my HD. The error from Dropbox began to show me what the issue was. It was trying to find settings in a location at C:\Users\Rod (and below). But much to my surprise I discovered that my Windows profile was now under C:\Users\Rod.000.

I asked about this on an Outlook forum (since the .pst file was similarly effected) and was told that the update had copied/moved (not sure which) my Windows profile from C:\Users\Rod to C:\Users\Rod.000.

After that I tried to find out how to fix this. I searched and found examples suggesting that I run the command **sfc /scannow** from an command prompt, running as Administrator. That is exactly what I did. However, that wasn't successful, either. I got this message:

```
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.
```

So next I started looking up the "unable to fix some of them" errors. I found a LOT of examples of people experiencing that issue, but all of them describe scenarios I am not experiencing. For example, they all described not being able to see their files, music, etc. I don't have that problem at all. I can see all my files, music, etc. But when I log into my account, Windows does seem to think that I've never done that on this machine before (completely wrong, I've had this machine for at least 4 years) and wants me to set up my profile, which I don't do, I skip out of it and continue to log in. My guess is that because I'm doing that, its not messed me up completely.

But that still leaves me with the problem of having a misplaced Windows profile. How do I fix it, now that the **sfc /scannow** didn't work? And the instructions that the sfc command issued are not, for me, helpful. I do not know what it means when it says, "For online repairs...", "For offline repairs..." These instructions seemed better suited to a PC Tech with experience at resolving these issues. I am not that person. So, how do I fix this issue, please?

Comment: Without the log (CBS.log), and knowing which files are corrupt, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: If you are just worried about the Outlook file you can transfer that to the new profile directory.  Likewise, you can copy the Dropbox folder, to the new profile.  It might be possible to use the old profile directory, but there likely was a reason, Windows created a new profile (unclear what the reason might be based on the information you provided).

Comment: That profile name is indicative of a temporary profile, like you stated in the title. The question is, how do you know that? Because the body of your question isn’t clear on that. You should look in the windows event log right after logging in. I believe it will be in the system log if you are using a temporary profile and why the real profile cannot load. You may see several warnings or errors, many may not be related at all, but look for the profile one. Do you also see the original `C:\users\Rod` folder? See here also: https://www.ghacks.net/2018/03/16/use-dism-to-fix-issues-sfc-cant/

Comment: @Ramhound, I've saved the CBS.log file. What do I look for in the CBS.log file?

Comment: @Appleoddity, I hadn't thought of looking at the event logs. Obvious. Will do, when I can.

Comment: Its been suggested to me that I do a system restore. Unless I'm mistaken (please correct me if I'm wrong), a system restore only restores the registry to some previous period. So, if I'm correct, then a system restore won't reverse what the 1903 update did by moving my profile from C:\Users\Rod to C:\Users\Rod.000. BTW, now that I've had more time to work with my system as it currently is, I now see many other apps aren't working. They've lost details as to my credentials, etc.

Comment: Appleoddity I've searched through Event Viewer system log. Didn't see any mention of the original C:\Users\Rod. I also didn't notice any error around someone logging into Windows. I've run DISM commands using the /CheckHealth; everything seemed fine. /ScanHealth resulted in "The component store is repairable".

Comment: @Appleoddity I've finished following the steps in the page you referenced on ghacks.net. After running DISM /Online /Clean-Image /RestoreHealth it gave me a message of "The restore operation completed successfully." I thought it might be a good idea to reboot it, so I did. However, I find that my Windows profile is still under C:\Users\Rod.000.

Comment: @Rod Did you ever manage to solve this issue? I'm in the same "state" with my profile.

Comment: No, I did not @Scoregraphic. I'm just living with it.